# Blogdown and hugo not parsing html tags in markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, hugo, blogdown

I'm trying to build a website with `blogdown` in `R` and I'm not sure why html tags are no longer parsed properly. It used to work properly for me. I tested the code below in three new/different R projects (different Hugo themes) and nothing worked. However, when I try to knit or preview a regular `Rmd` or `md` file, the html tags are parsed correctly and everything works as intended.

For example, the following code in my markdown document has no effect on the text. Images also don't show up.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Link to Google</a>
<b>happy</b>
```

When I serve the site, what I see is just the following text, unformatted:

Link to Google
happy

Note that standard markdown syntax still works:

```
[Link to Google](https://www.google.com)
**happy**
```

Expected output

[Link to Google](https://www.google.com) **happy**

Does anyone have any clue what could be the problem? Appreciate any help anyone can provide! Thanks.

And below are my R session info. I'm using the latest version of Hugo (0.65.0) and `blogdown` (also tried the development version). I downgraded to Hugo 0.60.0 and it still didn't work.

```
> xfun::session_info()
R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6, RStudio 1.2.5033

Locale: en_CA.UTF-8 / en_CA.UTF-8 / en_CA.UTF-8 / C / en_CA.UTF-8 / en_CA.UTF-8

Package version:
  base64enc_0.1.3 bookdown_0.17   digest_0.6.24   evaluate_0.14   glue_1.3.1      graphics_3.6.2  grDevices_3.6.2
  highr_0.8       htmltools_0.4.0 jsonlite_1.6.1  knitr_1.28      magrittr_1.5    markdown_1.1    methods_3.6.2  
  mime_0.9        Rcpp_1.0.3      rlang_0.4.4     rmarkdown_2.1   stats_3.6.2     stringi_1.4.6   stringr_1.4.0  
  tinytex_0.19    tools_3.6.2     utils_3.6.2     xfun_0.12       yaml_2.2.1
```

Comment: After trying different Hugo versions, I realized Hugo 0.59 works. And Kevin also responded to my question below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IIRC, Hugo >=0.60 now uses Goldmark (see https://gohugo.io/news/0.60.0-relnotes/)
and so in order to use html tags in markdown file, you should add

```
[markup.goldmark.renderer]
unsafe = true
```

in your `config.toml` file (see the link above for the other formats).

Comment: Thank you, Kevin! I discovered that through trial-and-error right when you responded! I tried Hugo 0.59 and it worked. But now I'll use 0.65 and add those two lines in my config.toml. Thanks again.

Comment: :) BTW, I am also using Hugo >0.60 and I really love the new features!