# Image Processing in Hugo

Tags: hugo, hugo-shortcode

I am using the following code `{{< figure src="../img/img.png" title="the image title" >}}` to display image on hugo website and it works fine. I found this piece of code from: [Add image to webpage which uses hugo framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46787540/add-image-to-webpage-which-uses-hugo-framework)

Now I wanted to do some image processing and was using the following link: https://gohugo.io/content-management/image-processing/

I was trying to use the following lines of code:

```
{{ $image := resources.Get "images/sunset.jpg" }}

{{ $image := resources.GetRemote "https://gohugo.io/img/hugo-logo.png" }}
```

For first line in above code, the folder structure is as follows. Inside the blog-code(root folder) I created `assets/images`, with sunset.jpg inside. It does not work i.e. image is not displayed on the page.

**Folder Structure**

`blog-code/assets/images/sunset.jpg`

The second line in above code is fetching a remote image. It also does not work.

I have tried following link, [Processing images in Hugo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63767874/processing-images-in-hugo),  and few other links but not able to solve the issue.

Please guide, where I am getting wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> It does not work i.e. image is not displayed on the page.

This code:

```
{{ $image := resources.Get "images/sunset.jpg" }}
```

does not display an image, it only sets the variable $image.

Answer (score 1):

`{{ $image := resources.Get "images/sunset.jpg" }}` <- you're getting the image resource and assigning to a variable

`<img src="{{$image.Permalink}}">` <- now you are giving the image resources URI to the src attribute

You're referenced link DOES show this exact pattern.

Reading the Hugo Docs for Image processing:
https://gohugo.io/content-management/image-processing/#readout

Seems like what you need so you do not fall prey to misunderstanding.

Comment: When i make use of `{{ $image := resources.Get “images/sunset.png” }}` , it shows up as in the following link: https://naresh-chaurasia.github.io/connect2naresh/experiments/

I am new to hugo and not sure if anything else is required to make it work.

Comment: Literally input: 
{{ $image := resources.Get "images/sunset.jpg" }}
<img src="{{$image.Permalink}}">

Comment: I have checked in the entire code here: https://github.com/Naresh-Chaurasia/blog-code-git

Comment: I tried a number of things. It seems like `<img/>` tag is not working. I have checked in the code at the above link.

Comment: The problem was happening as hugo was not parsing html tags. Please refer to following link for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60329235/blogdown-and-hugo-not-parsing-html-tags-in-markdown

I added following code to `config.toml` and now it is showing images.

```[markup.goldmark.renderer]unsafe = true```